# Opinion adjective + opinion adjective

Tags: adjectives

We often use (opinion + fact) adjective for example : ***"an interesting young man"*** , ***"a nice long table"*** etc.

And also we use (adverb+adjective) for example : ***"a reasonably cheap restaurant"*** , ***"an extremely good game"*** etc.

As far as I know we don't use (opinion + opinion) adjective instead of (adverb+opinion adjective)

I mean we don't use ***"a reasonable cheap restaurant"*** instead of ***"a reasonably cheap restaurant"***

Is there any rule about this context I don't know ? or Is it just a more idiomatic way to use?

Comment: I don't think there's any rule about that.  You can certainly say "a beautiful, tasteful dress", which is two opinions in a row.  In your examples, *reasonably* and *extremely* just happen to modify the opinion-adjectives that fall after them, but there's no rule that says they have to modify opinions and not facts.

Comment: You can use ***"a reasonable cheap restaurant"*** but it does not mean the same thing. It means the restaurant is cheap and [the food] is reasonable.

Comment: We can use 'opinion and opinion', e.g. 'He is an interesting and reasonable young man.'

Answer (score 1):

> (opinion[A] + opinion[B]) adjective[C]

Adjectives modify nouns. A is an adjective, B is an adjective, and C is a noun.

This means C is A and B.

> interesting young man = The man is young and interesting
>
> (adverb[A] + opinion[B] adjective[C])

Adverbs modify verbs or adjectives.

C is B.  A provides more information about B.

So the adverb is modifying the adjective, and the *modified adjective* is then modifying the noun.

> a reasonably cheap restaurant

"Reasonably restaurant" isn't something you can take away from this sentence.  It's a cheap restuarant.  How cheap?  Reasonably cheap.

Now - you can say *reasonable restaurant* to mean a restaurant that is reasonable in some way, and one of those ways can be price.  Context has to support this.

Comment: Heh heh. Maybe it's a restaurant that is willing to listen to a cogent presentation of the facts and logic and admit when it's wrong. <big wide grin>